# HTTP/2 protocol WINDOW_UPDATE with STREAM_ID 0

Tags: http2

According to [RFC7540](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#WINDOW_UPDATE):

> The WINDOW_UPDATE frame can be specific to a stream or to the entire
> connection. In the former case, the frame's stream identifier
> indicates the affected stream; in the latter, **the value "0" indicates
> that the entire connection is the subject of the frame.**

Am I correct to interpret it as WINDOW_UPDATE with STREAM_ID 0 increments the window of all streams? Or should I interpret it as all streams share the same window? i.e. After sending 10KB to STREAM 1 and 20KB to STREAM 3, the window size of STREAM 0 (shared by 1 and 3) is reduced by 30KB? Effectively, STREAM 1 and 3 also have their window reduced by 30KB.

Now, when an HTTP/2 peer sends WINDOW_UPDATE on STREAM 0 but also send WINDOW_UPDATE for individual streams, how should the recipient handle it?

Answer (score 1):

The connection window is shared across all streams of that connection.

> After sending 10KB to STREAM 1 and 20KB to STREAM 3, the window size of STREAM 0 (shared by 1 and 3) is reduced by 30KB?

Correct.

> Effectively, STREAM 1 and 3 also have their window reduced by 30KB.

This is not correct though.

If STREAM 1 and 3 have an initial window of 64 KiB, and the connecton window has an initial size of 256 KiB, after you send 10 KiB on STREAM 1, then STREAM 1 is unaffected by what has been sent on STREAM 3, so still has 54 KiB available to send, while STREAM 3 has 34 KiB available.

You get a different behavior when the sum of the windows of all the streams is less than the connection window.

In the example above, let's assume the connection window is 110 KiB rather than 256 KiB.
In this case, STREAM 1 sends 10 and STREAM 3 sends 30, so the connection has 70 KiB remaining.

This means that STREAM 1 can send its remaining 54 KiB without stalling, and then it will stall because it exhausted its own stream window.
However, there are still 70-54=16 KiB available in the connection window.
These can be used by STREAM 3, so that it has now sent a total of 30+16=46 KiB.

At this point, even if STREAM 3 window has still 64-46=18 KiB of window available, the connection window is exhausted and all the streams are now stalled (i.e. they cannot send), regardless of how many bytes they have available in their own stream windows.

When the other peer sends a WINDOW_UPDATE for STREAM 0 of 50 KiB, the sender connection window will be reopened at 50 KiB, and at this point STREAM 1 still cannot send (because its stream window is exhausted), but STREAM 3 will be able to send its remaining 18 KiB, leaving 50-18=32 KiB in the connection window available for other streams.